# Lightning Out Flow

Tags: visualforce, lightning-apps, visual-flows, lightning-out

I am trying to Render Lightning Flow Runtime in a Visualforce Page.

Lightning out app Code:

Visual Force Page Code:

var recordId= "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}";

```
         var statusChange = function (event) {
           if(event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {
              // Control what happens when the interview finishes

              var outputVariables = event.getParam("outputVariables");
              var key;
              for(key in outputVariables) {
                 if(outputVariables[key].name === "myOutput") {
                    // Do something with an output variable
                 }
              }
           }
        };
        $Lightning.use("c:LightningOutApp", function() {
           // Create the flow component and set the onstatuschange attribute
           $Lightning.createComponent("lightning:flow", {"onstatuschange":statusChange},
              "flowContainer",
              function (component) {
                 // Set the input variables


                 // Start an interview in the flowContainer div, and 
                 // initializes the input variables.
                 component.startFlow("NewFlow", recordId);
              }
           );
        });

     </script>
  </body>
```

The flow controls are not rendering properly.

[image]